# do all real polynomials include constant poly?

Tags: polynomials

Do all real polys include constant polys? or 0 ?

and I just want to make sure

is integral of 0 always 0?

I think it is yes for both questions that I mentioned above.

I just want to double check it so that I might not make stupid mistake

Answer (score 1):

A polynomial of degree $n$ can be represented as $$p_n(x) = a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1 x^1 + a_0 x^0.$$
So, a polynomial of degree $0$ is $p_0(x) = a_0$, where $a_0$ is any constant. So $f(x)=0$ is definitely a polynomial.

Also, given a constant $C$, $$\frac{d}{dx}C = 0$$
$$ dC = 0 \ dx$$
$$ \int dC = \int 0 \ dx $$
$$ C = \int 0 \ dx.$$
So, the integral of $0$ is a constant.

Comment: integral of 0 is constant?

Comment: what about definite integral from 0 to 1 ?

Comment: Yes, the indefinite integral of $0$ is a constant. However, the definite integral of $0$ from $a$ to $b$ is $0$, since the definite integral represents the area under the curve to the $x$-axis. You could also arrive at that answer analytically, by using the fundamental theorem of calculus.